# LSTM ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I faced a problem when I try to fit the model, here is my build model and the shape of my train and test data:

```
import keras
def buildModel(dataLength, labelLength):
    price=Input(shape=(dataLength, 51),name='price') 
#     price = Input(shape = (dataLength,1),name='price')
    sentiment = Input(shape=(dataLength, 51),name='sentiment')

    priceLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(price)
    sentimentLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(sentiment)

    output = keras.layers.concatenate(
        [priceLayers,sentimentLayers,]
    )
    output = Dense(labelLength, activation='linear',name='output')(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs = [price,sentiment],
        outputs=[output]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse')
    return model
```

---

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model

lstm = buildModel(22234,1)
lstm.fit([trainX,trainS],[trainY],validation_data=(
        [testX,testS],
        [testY]),epochs = 10)
```

---

```
trainX.shape = (1, 22234, 51)
testX.shape = (1, 9500, 51)

trainY.shape = (22234,)
testY.shape = (9500,)

trainS.shape = (1, 22234, 51)
testS.shape = (1, 9500, 51)
```

Error shows:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-4d75b702c980> in <module>()
      5 lstm.fit([trainX,trainS],[trainY],validation_data=(
      6         [testX,testS],
----> 7         [testY]),epochs = 10
      8 )
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 22234 target samples.
```

But I don't understand why it says my input and target samples have different size, is it because in X and S has 3 dimensions but Y only has 2D? My thought is: the input has to be 3D, so I reshape X and S; however, Y is the label, and it do not need to reshape

Answer (score 0):

The batch dimension for inputs and targets needs to be the same. This needs to be dimension 0.

```
trainX.shape = (1, 22234, 51)
```

needs to be: `(22234, 51, 1)` when the outputs are shaped as `(22234,)`.

Do not try to use 1 as time_step dimension since an LSTM with a single time step doesn't make sense.

The input dimensions should be `(batch_size, time_steps, n_features)`. No need to specify batch_size when building the model. So that shapes you declare should be `(time_steps, n_features)`. For a sequence of N measurements N is the time_steps and n_features is the number of values measured at a time.

Comment: If I change the input shape into (22234, 51, 1), I get the error: Error when checking input: expected price to have shape (22234, 51) but got array with shape (51, 1). I am quite confuse why it got the array shape(51,1) instead of (2234,51)...

Comment: The dataset shape and the Input() shape must match; so you need to change the Input() node shape accordingly. Your model shows an LSTM... an LSTM is an operation on a sequence of elements such that the data is transformed by observing the sequence. It needs a 3-D shape such that the time_step dimension is greater than 1. Thus the recommendation for you to use a shape of (batch_size, sequence_lengh, 1); which in your case probably corresponds to and input shape of (51, 1,).

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this field, I still don't understand. I have reshape my train data: trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1],1)), so it change from (22234, 51) to (22234, 51,1). Is this what you means  for (batch_size, sequence_lengh, 1) ? But  I still got eroor: expected price to have shape (22234, 51) but got array with shape (51, 1) when I make lstm = buildModel(22234,51)  and fit the model. And if I change lstm = buildModel(51,1), it then tell me :  expected price to have shape (51, 51) but got array with shape (51, 1)
Is this  because my def(buildModel) wrong